# display lines in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, shapes, stage, document-class

I am baffled by this function, which is called prior to this with parameters 22 and 58 for xVal ad yVal respectively. It doesn't display anything when the swf is compiled and tested, and it's error free. The code is in the document class:

```
    private function mLine(xVal : int, yVal : int) {
        var rCol = 0x0000FF;
        var incr = Math.round((Math.random() * 20) + 8);
        lns.push(new Shape());
        var i = lns.length - 1;

        this.addChild(lns[i]);
        lns[i].graphics.moveTo(xVal, yVal);
        lns[i].graphics.lineStyle(10, rCol);
        lns[i].graphics.lineTo(xVal, yVal + 20);
        lns[i].name = incr;
        trace("lns[" + i + "] x is " + lns[i].x); // outputs 'lns[0] x is 0'
        trace("xVal is " + xVal); // outputs 'xVal is 22'
        trace("yVal is " + yVal); //outputs 'yVal is 58'
        trace(stage.contains(lns[i])); // outputs 'true'
    }
```

Comment: Your question is called "stupid question", yet I see no question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have declared `private var lns = [];` somewhere, it draws a blue line (20px straight down from the given position).

> It doesn't display anything

That means you probably don't have an object of that class on the stage. In your document class, you should use `addChild` to display an instance of the class containing `mLine`. mLine needs to be called somehow obviously. You could do this in the class' constructor, but you'd need to remove the last trace statement to avoid a null pointer error, because `stage` would be `null` then.

Edit: Missed that you said it is in the Document class. So, try and see if drawing anything else works. The problem doesn't seem to be with this function.

Comment: so the problem was even simpler than all of this. My movieclip was very tall, 5000px high, and when I tested it, it was only showing the bottom of the screen, so I couldn't see the blue line which DOES appear.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems like it should work. I have rewrote it to conform better to ActionScript 3 best practices

```
private function drawLine(xVal:int, yVal:int):void 
{
    var lineColor:uint = 0x0000FF;

    var lineShape:Shape = new Shape();
    //lineShape.name = String(Math.round((Math.random() * 20) + 8));
    lineShape.graphics.lineStyle(10, lineColor);
    lineShape.graphics.moveTo(xVal, yVal);
    lineShape.graphics.lineTo(xVal, yVal + 20);
    addChild(lineShape);
    lines.push(lineShape);
}
```

The x and y properties of your shape will both be zero because you never set them. you are just drawing lines inside the shape at the xVal and yVal. You could do the same thing like this:

```
private function mLine(xVal:int, yVal:int) 
{
    var lineColor:uint = 0x0000FF;

    var lineShape:Shape = new Shape();
    //lineShape.name = String(Math.round((Math.random() * 20) + 8));
    lineShape.graphics.lineStyle(10, lineColor);
    lineShape.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
    lineShape.graphics.lineTo(0, 20);
    lineShape.x = xVal;
    lineShape.y = yVal;
    addChild(lineShape);
    lines.push(lineShape);
}
```

Not sure why its not showing up at all for you though.